# GPG/Kleopatra: Import missing certificate for email

Tags: gpg4win

I received an encrypted+signed email. How do I import the key used to sign it?

```
Signed on 2015-09-29 12:01 with unknown certificate 0xAFF6229E09591DDB.
The signature is invalid: No public certificate to verify the signature
```

Can I do it directly from Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

To verify a mail's signature you need the public key of the sender. You can normally get the public key (here called certificate) from the sender of the mail or from a public key server. But if you want to be sure, that you got no faked public key, you should verify it's fingerprint with the sender (e.g. by phone).

I am not sure if gpg4win's Outlook integration can handle signature verification at all. I for me self use gpg4o ([gpg4o](http://www.gpg4o.com)) which is much more reliable than the open source solutions and offers a very smooth integration into Outlook.

Edit:
I just looked for the key and I found a public key for Daniel xxxx Hxxxx on the key server hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:11371